# Vitest, dotenv-expand failed to expand env vars

Tags: typescript, testing, environment-variables, vitest

Inside my index.test.ts file, I have the following code:

```
import { it,describe, expect } from "vitest";
import {readEvents,readCommands} from "../index";

describe("command and event loaders",() => {
    it("event loader should work proper",() => {
        let el = readEvents;
        expect(el).not.toThrowError;
    })
    it("command loader should work properly",() => {
        let el = readCommands;
        expect(el).not.toThrowError;
    })
})
```

When I run; vitest --run --reporter verbose, I get that following error:

*Error: dotenv-expand failed to expand env vars. Maybe you need to escape `$`?*

Answer (score 4):

Check in your .env if some value contains '$', if so then you must escape it

Comment: So absurd :( What if it's a password

Comment: If you haven't tried it, don't say it doesn't work, if I'm indicating this it's because it worked for me, I have no idea why but it worked. You must enclose your password between " " no ' '
Example: for the password Hol$01
DB_PASSWORD="Hol\$01"

Comment: it worked for me inside the password as well

Answer (score 0):

Check in your .env file for '$' and use it as

> "\$"

and it'll fix your error. Thanks

Comment: This is a thin rephrasing of the existing upvoted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75001473/7733418). In order to avoid the impression that you are trying to get reputation by copying without own contribution, please try to at least provide a different an insightful new angle of explanation.